# Assigning value to each iterative select element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

```
                 @foreach($users as $user)
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="select_month" name="month" class="form-control">
                                <option value="01" >Jan</option>
                                <option value="02" >Feb</option>
                                <option value="03">Mar</option>
                                <option value="04" >Apr</option>
                                <option value="05" >May</option>
                                <option value="06">Jun</option>
                                <option value="07" >Jul</option>
                                <option value="08" >Aug</option>
                                <option value="09">Sep</option>
                                <option value="10" >Oct</option>
                                <option value="11" >Nov</option>
                                <option value="12">Dec</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="select_year" name="year" class="form-control">
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="url" class="btn-group mr5">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="url('{{ $user->id }}')">Invoice</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

The above code displays 10 users. I need to get the month and year of the selected user in order to pass through the url.

```
<script>
    function url(id){
        var month = $('#select_month').val();
        var year = $('#select_year').val();
        var url = "{{ web_url() }}/user/invoice/generate?id="+id+"&month="+month+"&year="+year;
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

The above script returns the selected month and year for the first user and undefined for the rest. Since, i am new to this suggest me an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's exactly what happens when you have duplicate IDs. An `id` is unique on a given document. Change all IDs to classes unless they are unique and post the generated HTML (2 iterations would be enough) and not PHP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by above code you are creating multiple elements with same id. Try appending a counter to each ID `id="select_month"+i` (use appropriate PHP syntax as am not aware of PHP) where i would be the loop counter.

And in your function pass the current index

```
function url(id,i){

        var month = $('#select_month'+i).val();
        var year = $('#select_year'+i).val();
        var url = "{{ web_url() }}/user/invoice/generate?id="+id+"&month="+month+"&year="+year;
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoh3cb7x/)

Comment: But when i did like above, its showing undefined. I have added the unique id to select element.

Comment: @karthick : please check this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eoh3cb7x/). You need to implement something similar to this based on your need. Please see how each `select` and url divs have unique ids.